# No command MCC found

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, mcc

I am trying to create an executable using Matlab 2013a in Ubuntu 14.04, and after some research, I understood the following command, creates the executable

```
    mcc -mv matlabfile.m
```

However, when I run this command, I get following error

```
    No command 'mcc' found, but there are 33 similar ones
    mcc: command not found
```

Is this an error due to Matlab installation or should I include the compiler into any path variable, so that I can access it using the command mcc.? How do I solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

I ran the *ver* command in my matlab and am showing the partial output, just to prove it includes Maltab Compiler.

```
    Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 8.2            (R2013a)
    Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 3.3        (R2013a)
    MATLAB Builder JA                                     Version 2.2.6      (R2013a)
    MATLAB Coder                                          Version 2.4        (R2013a)
    MATLAB Compiler                                       Version  4.18.1     (R2013a)
    MATLAB Distributed Computing Server                   Version 6.2        (R2013a)
    MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 3.14       (R2013a)
    Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 3.7        (R2013a)
    Model Predictive Control Toolbo
```

Comment: See: [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9433-mcc-command](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9433-mcc-command)

Comment: I did come across this link. I think he's saying for windows, that his compiler might be missing. I can find my compiler in my matlab, in ubuntu, in my Matlab. Is there anything am missing?

Comment: Do you own a copy of the of the Matlab Compiler toolbox?

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can verify that? if I open Maltab and Apps tab, I can find a button saying Matlab compiler, which is allowing me to choose a main program and its dependencies.

Comment: That apps tab should be fine. To be sure, run the `ver` command, which prints out all the toolboxes you own.

Comment: I did, and found Matlab compiler there. have updated my question

Comment: has it got something to do with ubuntu's libraries understanding MCC as a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Matlab Compiler toolbox installed, you can either run the `mcc.m` function through the Matlab command line:

```
mcc -mv matlabfile.m
```

Or you can run the `mcc` binary directly in your shell:

```
/path/to/matlab/bin/mcc -mv matlabfile.m
```

Or you can add the folder containing the `mcc` binary to you PATH and then run it:

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/matlab/bin/"
mcc -mv matlabfile.m
```

Comment: the path is what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Linux Matlab with me, so if I have the location of `mcc` a little bit off, please update. I thought it was in `bin`.

Comment: can the executable created b used across machines?

Comment: How to work it around to include all the dependencies?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Those belong as new questions.

Comment: can you give me some direction mate? looks like you do know @drhagen